# Single gadget, preferably USB, for switching on and off a mains socket from a Windows laptop

Tags: usb

My memory tells me that that Sinclair ZX81 could easily control a mains socket and therefore allow a user to do things like control the watering of pot plants without needing to get a soldering iron out or learn hacking skills.

Unfortunately, my memory seems to have been wrong, because I looked in the ZX81 manual and it contains nothing about this function. So I must be thinking of another very early model of home computer.

Anyway, what I need is a hardware device that I can plug into my Windows laptop, preferably into one of its USB sockets, and then wire a mains socket into it that the driver software for the device will be able to turn on and off.

I am aware of "smart plugs", but this is not what I am asking about.

Answer (score 0):

This is partially an answer, as you've included "single" in your question and this is not a single item, but a full system.

X10 has been around since the last century, originally connected via serial port (DB-9!) to a bulky box of switches, which could be activated manually, of course. It's since evolved into something akin to today's technology.

X10 has a [puck-like device](https://www.homecontrols.com/X10-USB-PC-Receiver-XTCM19A) to connect to a computer via USB. The non-single aspect of this system is that one is required to have one or more modules as the target for the software to control them.

[image: X10 usb connected transceiver]
image from linked site

This also provides for greater selection of the devices/modules you will be able to operate from the PC.